Joining 3 graphs together in R
I wrote this R code that joins 3 graphs together based on a random node in each graph:
library(igraph)
library(RColorBrewer)

create_connected_graph <- function(n) {
  g <- make_ring(n)
  extra_edges <- sample(1:5, 1)
  for(i in 1:extra_edges) {
    v1 <- sample(1:n, 1)
    v2 <- sample(setdiff(1:n, c(v1, neighbors(g, v1))), 1)
    g <- add_edges(g, c(v1, v2))
  }
  return(g)
}

g1 <- create_connected_graph(10)
g2 <- create_connected_graph(8)
g3 <- create_connected_graph(12)

colors <- brewer.pal(3, "Pastel1")
V(g1)$color <- colors[1]
V(g2)$color <- colors[2]
V(g3)$color <- colors[3]
V(g1)$name <- 1:vcount(g1)
V(g2)$name <- (max(V(g1)$name) + 1):(max(V(g1)$name) + vcount(g2))
V(g3)$name <- (max(V(g2)$name) + 1):(max(V(g2)$name) + vcount(g3))

combined_graph <- disjoint_union(g1, g2, g3)

v1 <- sample(V(combined_graph)[V(combined_graph)$color == colors[1]], 1)
v2 <- sample(V(combined_graph)[V(combined_graph)$color == colors[2]], 1)
v3 <- sample(V(combined_graph)[V(combined_graph)$color == colors[3]], 1)
combined_graph <- add_edges(combined_graph, c(v1, v2, v1, v3))

plot_graph <- function(g, title) {
  if (title == "Combined Graph") {
    l <- layout_with_graphopt(g, niter = 500, charge = 0.01)
  } else {
    l <- layout_with_fr(g)
  }
  
  plot(g, 
       vertex.label = V(g)$name, 
       vertex.size = 30, 
       vertex.label.color = "black", 
       vertex.label.cex = 0.8, 
       edge.width = 2,
       edge.color = "gray50",
       main = title, 
       layout = l,
       margin = c(0,0,0,0))
}

From here, I plot the results:
par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=c(1,1,2,1))

plot_graph(g1, "Graph 1")
plot_graph(g2, "Graph 2")
plot_graph(g3, "Graph 3")

plot_graph(combined_graph, "Combined Graph")

par(mfrow=c(1,1))


I am wondering: Is it possible that in the final joined/fused graph, is it possible to connect these 3 graphs based on specific nodes? For example, node 6 is merged with node 11, node 13 with node 30, and (13, 30, 5)?
Thank you!

From this code you are joining v1 to v2 and v1 to v3. Rather than randomly sampling values for v1, v2, and v3, just specify the nodes you actually want to join. For example add_edges(combined_graph, c("6", "11", "13", "30")) |> plot(). That is assuming by "merge" you mean connecting with an edge. Otherwise it's not clear exactly what you want.

I am not sure what you mean by "merge" exactly, but like the comments point out if you replace v1, v2, and v3 with the node names you want instead of random node names that would connect the graphs with edges between those nodes.
Assuming that by "merge" you mean to combine a node from each graph into one node in a combined graph then something like this would work using set_vertex_attr and union.igraph.
library(igraph)

create_connected_graph <- function(n) {
  g <- make_ring(n)
  extra_edges <- sample(1:5, 1)
  for(i in 1:extra_edges) {
    v1 <- sample(1:n, 1)
    v2 <- sample(setdiff(1:n, c(v1, neighbors(g, v1))), 1)
    g <- add_edges(g, c(v1, v2))
  }
  return(g)
}

g1 <- create_connected_graph(10)
g2 <- create_connected_graph(12)
g3 <- create_connected_graph(15)
V(g1)$name <- 1:vcount(g1)
V(g2)$name <- (max(V(g1)$name) + 1):(max(V(g1)$name) + vcount(g2))
V(g3)$name <- (max(V(g2)$name) + 1):(max(V(g2)$name) + vcount(g3))
# whatever nodes
v1 <- 6
v2 <- 11
v3 <- 25
# change names of nodes in g2 and g3 so that v1, v2, v3 are the same
g2 <- set_vertex_attr(g2, "name", value = gsub(v2, v1, names(V(g2)), fixed = TRUE))
g3 <- set_vertex_attr(g3, "name", value = gsub(v3, v1, names(V(g3)), fixed = TRUE))
combined_graph <- union(g1, g2, g3) # combine graphs, which should now have 1 overlapping node
plot(combined_graph, vertex.size = 10)

